# How can I select multiple rows using parameters from an array in Perl's DBI module?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am required to pull out rows corresponding to column `name`. The rows being pulled out correspond to address in array `@values`. Following is my code:

```
use strict;
use DBI;

open (FH, "/user/address") or die $!;
my@values=<FH>;
close(FH);
my @names;

my $query = "Select name from table where address = ?";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $query ) or die "could not prepare statement\n", $dbh->errstr;
foreach my $value(@values){ #@values contain list of address
        $sth->execute($value) or die "could not execute statement $query\n", $sth->errstr;
        while ($result = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()){
               my $name_reqd = $result->{name};
               print "Name Req: $name_reqd\n"; #not printing anything 
               push (@names, $name_reqd);
        }
}
print "@names\n"; #not printing anything
```

But when I print `@names`, I don't get any output, I am unsure as to what is going wrong.

Comment: The code says "use strict" at the top.

Comment: Please `use warnings` is probably what @Ivan Nevostruev meant.

Comment: I have no way of knowing what he meant to say, so I just go by the words he actually wrote.

Comment: If you have not already done so, it is worthwhile to learn how to use the Perl debugger. I'll bet you could step through this code, see what the return value of `$sth->fetchrow_hashref()` is, and debug this program in two minutes.

Comment: Have you declare "my @names" ? I can't find it anywhere. It should be declared outside the foreach loop

Comment: Well, it took me a while to figure out how to put the URL in my answer, but try specifying lower case column names or just use `selectcol_arrayref`: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#FetchHashKeyName%5F%28string%2C%5Finherited%29

Comment: You can hardcode the values into @values. If it prints the data from the database, it means that there is something wrong when you pull out the data from the file to the @values

Comment: @tinker: In your comment right below the accepted answer you say *@Ivan: nope, adding chomp does not help. – tinker 41 mins ago* Do you think this is funny?

Comment: @tinker: In future, it would be better to post actual code rather than posting snippets of non-functioning code. You seem to have sent a lot of people on a wild goose chase. However, the downvotes and close votes don't seem like the correct reaction, since you're new here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this code is file reading. Code `my @values=<FH>;` reads all lines with new-line (`\n`) symbol at the end. It should be manually removed in this case. You can do it using [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function:

```
open (FH, "/user/address") or die $!;
my @values = <FH>;
chomp(@values);
close(FH);
```

**Update:**
I think it's not searching anything because it just can't find. Addresses usually have spaces within. Query `Select name from table where address = ?` will find only exact equal addresses (letter case is the only thing ignored). For example " a" is not equal to "a" in sql.

Comment: It isn't 100% but that looks likely.

Comment: @Ivan: nope, adding chomp does not help.

Comment: Do you mean after the while loop? $result has no value/defination before while loop.

Comment: @tinker: yes after loop... it will show you values of variables, which can be usefull to undestand what's happening. But the code looks good so far. I think it's not searching anything because it just can't find. Addresses usually have spaces within. Query `Select name from table where address = ?` will find only exact equal addresses (letter case is the only thing ignored). For example " a" is not equal to "a" in sql.

Comment: "I think it's not searching anything because it just can't find. Addresses usually have spaces within. " of Ivan answer helped.

Comment: I've added that comment as part of answer

Answer (score 4):

I see a few things:

- you aren't declaring `@names` before you use it, which means it is being automatically declared at the scope of its first use: inside the while loop. Moreover a new copy is destroyed and created on every iteration of the loop, and then a new (empty) one is created when you call `print`. Adding `use warnings;` would catch this.
- (as mobrule and others have said) you may not be accessing the data correctly out of `$result`. Try adding `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($result);` in the top line of the while loop to see what data you have read in.
- I'm not sure what format you are using in `/usr/address`, but if it has more than one line, you're only reading the first line from that file. You can read in the entire file in one go by localizing `$/` first (see [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)). Moreover (as Ivan said), this string will still have a newline at the end: use `chomp` to strip it (perhaps after splitting into lines, if you slurped more than one). See [perldoc -f chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) and [perldoc -f split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

Between these points, you should have enough debugging data being printed that you should easily see where you went wrong.

Comment: printing $result before while loop, print : $VAR1=undef;

Comment: @Ether +1 for summarizing useful debugging ideas. @tinker I am giving up on you: I do not think the code you are showing us is actually the code that exhibits the problem. Or, your input does not match what's in the database. Either way, we do not have real information that can help us give real answers. Voting to close your question as a not a real question.

Comment: @tinker: you're dumping `$result` before it has either been declared or assigned? No wonder it's empty. Try dumping it just after you assign it in the while loop, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

untested, but shouldn't you access your fields like this.

```
my $name_reqd = $result[0];
```

This is because you are using fetchrow_array().

Comment: +1 The OP first had `fetchrow_array()` in his post before he edited it. So the downvote on this post was not deserved.

Answer (score 2):

You should ensure that the database driver is [returning column names in lower case](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#FetchHashKeyName_%28string%2C_inherited%29). Also, use [`selectcol_arrayref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#selectcol_arrayref) for this type of query:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use File::Slurp;

my @values = read_file '/user/address';
chomp @values;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    # appropriate parameters
);

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT name FROM table WHERE address = ?'
) or die sprintf 'Cannot prepare: %s', $dbh->errstr;

my @names;

for my $value ( @values ) {
    my $names = $dbh->selectcol_arrayref(
        $sth,  {},  $value
    ) or die sprintf 'Cannot select col: %s',  $dbh->errstr;

    push @names,  @$names;
    print "'$_'\n" for @$names;
);

print "@names\n";
```

Comment: Considering you told me not to post non-answers, what on earth do you mean by this? The syntax of tinker's question is correct, you are simply giving a different way to achieve the same result, and not even answering the question.

Comment: Going by the documentation, selectcol_arrayref combines prepare and execute. I dont think that is the problem I am facing. My prepare and execute statements work. the issue is either with the '$result' part or the while loop.

Comment: @Kinopiko: A question such as *Is the name of the table really table?* is a non-answer.

Comment: @Sinan: Your code will most probably work. But, I am interested in knowing what is wrong with my code? Why is not printing anything? Thanks!

Comment: I *think* adding a `print Dumper $result;` in the body of the `while` loop will reveal the answer.

Comment: @Kinopiko Because you keep posting those non-answer answers which should rightly be comments, you keep taking away the opportunity to earn additional badges for others and creating pressure to post quickly. The point is `selectcol_arrayref` does not depend the database driver returning keys in lower case, but I did not get a chance to write out my post because your non-answer answer popped up as I was typing my answer. So, post-edit-post-edit was how I responded to it.

Comment: So my rapid answer "forced" you to write your answer quickly. I'm very sorry about that. I'll try not to answer questions so quickly next time.

Answer (score 1):

DBI performs case conversion on column names, so it may be returing the result in the key "NAME" instead of "name".

What do you see if you `print keys %$result` after calling `$sth->fetchrow_hashref` ?

Comment: does not print any thing (just a new line).

Answer (score 0):

Is your table really called "table"? Maybe it should be `$table`, with `$table` set to the actual name of the table.

If you can, for example SQLite or MySQL have this, try running your query from the database command line.

Comment: Don't post non-answer answers.

Comment: This seems to me to be a valid answer. It's not the correct answer but I don't see how it is invalid or not an answer. It's perfectly possible that he'd forgotten the dollar sign.